# How to translate toDayDateTimeString method to other language?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to have show dates translated in "de" and in this format:

```
 Thu, Mar 8, 2018 - 6:30
```

I have in "app.php":

```
'locale' => 'de',
```

Then in a view Im using:

```
{{$post->date->toDayDateTimeString()}}
```

But the result still appears in "en":

```
 Thu, Mar 8, 2018 6:30 AM
```

But for example using other carbon method: `{$post->date->diffForHumans()}}` the result appears in "de", but I dont want that format, I want the `toDayDateTimeString()` format.

Do you know how to also have this format toDayDateTimeString() translated another language? So is possible to show the date like "Thu, Mar 8, 2018 - 6:30" in another language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the date translated to German, you'll have to set the appropriate [locale](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), before using `Carbon`.

As a test in your view, this should be enough:

```
<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE'); ?>

{{ $post->date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y %H:%M') }}
```

For other format options, refer to the [strftime()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function manual.

You will have to make sure that the locale you want is enabled in your system.

I'm gonna assume you're in a Linux environment, so you'll have to edit the `locale.gen` file (Arch Linux and Ubuntu have it in `/etc/locale.gen`, other distros might have it elsewhere), and uncomment the appropriate lines:

```
# de_DE ISO-8859-1
# de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

will have to be changed to

```
de_DE ISO-8859-1
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

After updating the `locale.gen` file, you'll need to run `locale-gen`, in order for those new locales you've just uncommented to be available from PHP.

`$ locale-gen`

Now confirm that the new locales are available, with:

`$ locale -a`

Now, go back to your browser and you'll successfully see the date/time translated.

**Edited:**
As we later found out, the `toDayDateTimeString()` method from the `Carbon` class, does not work with localisation, so the `formatLocalized()` has to be used.

Comment: Thanks, that "setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');" is in the AppServiceProvider.php?

Comment: It has to be set before you call the `toDayDateTimeString()` method, so wherever you see fit. I guess the `AppServiceProvider` could be a good place for it.

Comment: Thanks but its not working setting "setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');" in AppServiceProvider and then use "{{$post->date->toDayDateTimeString()}}". I check in osx the languages and regions setting and there is the language.

Comment: Also in "/usr/share/locale/" there are the files.

Comment: I have this in the AppServiceprovider:  public function boot()
    {

        \Carbon\Carbon::setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
    }.

Comment: Make sure you definitely have the `de_DE` locales available. Use `locale -a` to list what you have currently available. In regards to the `setlocale()` function, I mean the native PHP one, not the `Carbon` method. As a test, call it just before you call the `toDayDateTimeString()` method. Once it works, move it to a proper place, like `AppServiceProvider` or other place you see appropriate.

Comment: The de_DE are available. Like this "{{$post->date->setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE')->toDayDateTimeString()}}" it appears "Call to a member function toDayDateTimeString() on boolean".

Comment: Thanks but I'm not understanding. Are you say to in the file where  there is {{$post->date}} have before for example <?php  setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE') ?>? Because also dont works.

Comment: Like I previously said, you need to call `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE')` before you print the date/time. When running `locale -a` in the terminal, what does it show you? Is `de_DE` in the list? Again, follow the instructions. I can't make it simpler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167483/discussion-between-quetzy-garcia-and-johnz).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setLocale('de')` method.

Here is an example

```
<?php 
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('de')      
?>


{{$post->date->toDayDateTimeString()}}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but with that it appears "Call to a member function toDayDateTimeString() on boolean".

Comment: try `<?php 
\Carbon::setLocale('de')
 ?>`

Comment: With "<?php \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('de') ?>" I dont get any error.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel comes with `Carbon` package, if you set locale in your app. Carbon will parse the date automatically with the language choosen.

[Check this](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)

```
Carbon::setLocale('de');
echo Carbon::getLocale();                          // de
echo Carbon::now()->addYear()->diffForHumans();    // in 1 Jahr

Carbon::setLocale('en');
echo Carbon::getLocale();                          // en
```

Comment: Thanks, but with the toDayDateTimeString() method dont works, dont translates.

Comment: That method converts to string, it wont translate the date. For translation you need to setLocale with Carbon

Comment: You could set it globally. `class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // Localization Carbon

        \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks, I have that "\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));" in the AppServiceProvider and in "app.php" I have "    'locale' => 'de'," but "{{$post->date->toDayDateTimeString()}}" prints in "en".

Comment: can you try `Carbon::parse($post->date)->toDateTimeString()` ?

Comment: It appears "2018-03-08 06:30:00".

Comment: i think this would work `Carbon::parse($post->date)->toDayDateTimeString()`

Comment: Thanks, but still appear in "en".